# Download shared document with OneDrive API

Tags: c#, json, onedrive

I'm trying to download a Word document which is shared with a user using the OneDrive API.

I used the documentation from [this](https://dev.onedrive.com/drives/shared_with_me.htm) page. First I'm getting a list of shared files using the following code:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{    
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.onedrive.com");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer",
    <ACCESS TOKEN>);

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("/v1.0/drive/oneDrive.sharedWithMe");
}
```

As the documentation says I'm getting a driveItem resource. Documentation can be found [here](https://dev.onedrive.com/resources/item.htm). The response is this JSON:

```
{  
   "value":[  
      {  
         "@content.downloadUrl":"DOWNLOAD URL",
         "createdDateTime":"2017-03-09T09:08:19.227Z",
         "cTag":"CTAG",
         "eTag":"ETAG",
         "id":"ID",
         "lastModifiedDateTime":"2017-03-09T13:39:42.133Z",
         "name":"Word document.docx",
         "webUrl":"WEBURL",
         "remoteItem":{  
            "createdBy":{  
               "user":{  
                  "displayName":"username",
                  "id":"USERID"
               }
            },
            "fileSystemInfo":{  
               "createdDateTime":"2017-03-09T08:50:52.663Z",
               "lastModifiedDateTime":"2017-03-09T13:06:19.653Z"
            },
            "file":{  
               "hashes":{  
                  "sha1Hash":"23894BC4D8E941FFA861851F9B47DCBD9DB061C6"
               },
               "mimeType":"image/png"
            },
            "id":"REMOTE ID",
            "lastModifiedBy":{  
               "user":{  
                  "displayName":"username",
                  "id":"USER ID"
               }
            },
            "lastModifiedDateTime":"2017-03-09T13:39:28.497Z",
            "name":"Word document.docx",
            "parentReference":{  
               "driveId":"DRIVE ID"
            },
            "shared":{  
               "owner":{  
                  "user":{  
                     "displayName":"username",
                     "id":"DRIVE ID"
                  }
               }
            },
            "size":15854,
            "webUrl":"WEBURL"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Im using the downloadUrl from this JSON to download the file. The URL works so I can download the file and at first it looks like it's a word document. But it is actually a png file. I expect the mime type to be `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document` or any other mime type that belongs to .docx documents. but the JSON says the mime type is image/png. So I can't open the file using Word but I have to open it as an image. When opening as a image I can see the content of the file but i want the actual Word document.

I tried downloading the file in bytes and convert it to a Word document. No luck of course because the downloaded file is really a png...

How can I download the shared file as the document type I expect it to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the service whereby it's somehow returning the thumbnail instead of the content. While we investigate and resolve that you could work around it by pulling the `driveId` value out of `remoteItem.parentReference`, and the `id` value out of `remoteItem` and crafting a request like:

> https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drives/`driveid`/items/`id`/content

This will redirect you to a download URL that will give you what you want.

I'll circle back and update this answer when the issue has been resolved.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Using the id directly from the SharedItem doesn't work. I used remoteItem.id. Not sure if that is what you meant with the id value out of id. This solution works. I will accept your answer as a solution to the problem.

Comment: You're correct, I meant `remoteItem.id` - I'll update the answer to fix that.